# Set wmode attribute to transparent for the embed shortcode to make drop-down menu hover over YouTube embed in Internet Explorer

Tags: shortcode, embed, videos, youtube, oembed

When you hover over my drop-down menu using IE8 or IE9, the menu div will display behind the YouTube embedment. It works fine on all other browsers.

Upon research, I found out that many others have [the same problem](http://goo.gl/aIbUQ) and the solution is to set the `wmode` attribute to `transparent`. So for instance `<iframe width="578" height="325" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXX?wmode=transparent"></iframe>` or `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />`.

My question is, how do I adjust the Wordpress `[embed]` shortcode to set the `wmode` attribute to `transparent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the HTML output for oEmbed with `oembed_result`. Now test the HTTP host of the URL for `www.youtube.com` and add the parameter.

The  oEmbed result is cached in a post meta field to avoid too many requests. To update old posts I have added an activation helper that clears those cached content for Youtube embeds only.

```
<?php  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Add 'wmode' to video embeds */

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 't5_clear_oembed_cache' );
add_filter( 'oembed_result', 't5_oembed_wmode', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add "wmode=transparent" query string to youtube embeds.
 *
 * @wp-hook oembed_result
 * @param   string $html
 * @param   string $url
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_oembed_wmode( $html, $url )
{
    if ( 'www.youtube.com' !== parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        return $html;

    return str_replace( '=oembed', '=oembed&amp;wmode=transparent', $html );
}

/**
 * Clear oEmbed cache for all youtube embeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function t5_clear_oembed_cache()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT post_id, meta_key
            FROM  `$wpdb->postmeta`
            WHERE  `meta_key` LIKE  '_oembed%'
                AND `meta_value` LIKE  '%youtube%'"
    );

    if ( ! $posts )
        return;

    /*
    return print '<pre>$posts = ' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $posts, TRUE ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE ) . "</pre>\n";
    /*/
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
        delete_post_meta( $post->post_id, $post->meta_key );
    /**/
}
```

Be aware this attribute makes the videos [inaccessible for screen reader users](http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=1921), so they cannot listen to them. So the better option would be to use the HTML5 output from Youtube instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting a solution to this issue. I tested this on IE8. I viewed an old post and it didn't work. Then I tested on a new post and it worked perfectly (the old post may have been cached although I did view it logged-in). My question is, do old posts need to be re-published for this to have effect? Nonetheless, this very issue was my final optimisation for old IE versions, thank you.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Oembed output is cached. You have to save the post again to get fresh output.

Comment: Got it! Also, does this take effect if the user added `youtube.com*` (without the `www`) and `https://www.yout*`...?

Comment: What the users has written doesn't matter; the oembed API will always return `www.youtube.com`. Wait a minute; I'm writing a cache refresher for that plugin right now. :)

Comment: @ChristineCooper See my update. Install the new plugin to get rid of all the old cached data.

Comment: This is a stellar answer! Thank you for the cache clearing code! Also, I am glad that this user brought the screenreader issue forward. For the moment, I will be adding the transparency but with a direct link to the Youtube link below the video. I have way to many IE8/9 visitors...

Answer (score 2):

That is a terrible idea as Flash movies with wmode transparent are not available to blind users with screenreaders any longer. Blind people do like to listen to videos, before that old chestnut comes up again. Use the HTML5 video embed to make it work for everyone and IE8 users getting a link to youtube. Don't make your accessibility suffer because old IE were terrible with embedding.

Comment: Can you provide code that would facilitate this? In particular, can you explain how to modify the `[embed]` shortcode mentioned in the question?